# How to describe leaving an access of a server

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, sentence

How can I formally write a sentence meaning that I am not using the server now and I have exited it?

Comment: How about, "I am logged off of the server."?

Comment: Please flesh out your question. This could be written in a large number of ways, none better than any other. You might get good advice in the [writer's chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/168/the-overlook-hotel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have logged off from the server. (or *logged out*)
>
> I am disconnected from the server.

If it's formal *and technical*, then it might be better to say "I am not actively using the server" for a stateless protocol (like the web), or "I have stopped using the server and my session has timed-out/expired" (like the web with cookie-based sessions). If you don't know the technical distinction of those from logging out, then it probably isn't a context where they matter, and you should just use "logged off from".

Comment: Normally, *logged off* means that you have invalidated your authentication credentials, and would require a new user/passwd combo to log back into it.  And yes, I prefer log *in/out* over *on/off* myself.  Doesn’t sound so ancient IBMish.

Comment: @tchrist I think *normally* it's a very vaguely defined word that's horribly inconsistent in usage, in both technical and non-technical contexts.